# Edge webdriver: spaces added to label text

Tags: selenium, webdriver, microsoft-edge

Edge webdriver: adding spaces to label text. For example

```
<input type='radio' id="myid" name="hello" value="1">
<label for="myid">SomeText</label>

WebElement labelElement = ...
labelElement.getText();  // returned value has a space before SomeText
```

Answer (score 0):

Code below is working fine with MS Edge and fetch label text properly without any extra space.

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"C:\Users\panchals\Desktop\tests\test1.html");

            try
            {           
                Console.WriteLine(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[@for='myid']")).Text);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            driver.Quit();
            driver.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<input type='radio' id="myid" name="hello" value="1">
<label for="myid">SomeText</label>
```

Output:

[image]

I also suggest you to to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer in your previous thread or try to update the status of the issue.

[webdriver edge: dispatchEvent for input element not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56727266/webdriver-edge-dispatchevent-for-input-element-not-working)